# How to add "tags" and "categories" when creating new post by `hugo new post.md`

Tags: hugo

To create a new post I run like:

`hugo new posts/post.md`

Then the file is generated like this:

```
---
title: "Post"
date: 2019-10-27T15:57:27+09:00
draft: true
---
```

Normally I use `tags` and `categories`, so it would be better if I can add it by default.

```
---
title: "Post"
date: 2019-10-27T15:57:27+09:00
draft: true
categories:
tags:
---
```

Where and how can I config the `hugo new` command to accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to edit the archetype file for `posts/*.md` files. Info about this is at:

1. https://gohugo.io/content-management/archetypes/
2. https://www.ii.com/themeless-gitless-intro-hugo/#_edit_the_archetype_for_new_md_content_files

In #2[*], it says: Use a text editor to open `archetypes/default.md`, which looks like this:

```
---
## Important: If this is a draft, next line should NOT begin with #
# draft: true
title: {{ replace .Name "-" " " | title }}
date: {{ now.Format "2006-01-02" }}
## below are user-defined parameters (lower case keys recommended)
subtitle:
tags:
  - tag1
  - tag2
---
```

You can put all kinds of things into an archetype, including body content.

I hope this helps,
N (stackoverflow posting newbie)

[*] I wrote #2. I hope it's OK to self link here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the terminology "Archetype".